# Accessing to remote server over sftp in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, sftp

I;m following [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html) official documentation to establish connection between my local and remote servers.
I have no problem with accessing to server through command line. Both commands

> ssh user@70.32.86.175
>
> sftp user@70.32.86.175

works fine.
However in PyCharm deployment setting, when I try to connect using `openSSH` I recieve an error: `Test connection failed`

I guess I might somewhere be wrong.